# a question on discrete topology on uncountable space

Tags: general-topology

Let ($X, T $) be a topological space where $X$ is a uncountable space and $T$ is the discrete topology . Then it is given that $x$ is not a limit point of the sequence  $x, x,$ . . . considered as a set, although it is an adherent point of the set.

But I could not find the proof. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Some_facts).

Answer (score 2):

In the discrete topology, every set and particularly every singleton is open.
The singleton $\{x\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, making $x$ an isolated point.

A more general statement holds: No isolated point is the limit point of any set. This is described and proven [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Some_facts). (It’s really just the definitions of *limit point* vs. *isolated point*.)

Oh, and for $x$ to be a limit point of a sequence $(x_n)_{n ∈ ℕ}$, by definition it needs to be a limit point of the set $\{x_n;\, n ∈ ℕ\}$.

The point $x$ is still the limit of the constant sequence $(x,x,…)$ just as $0$ would be the limit, but no limit point of the constant sequence $(0,0,…)$ in $ℝ$ with the usual topolgy.